# Is there a resource of complementary monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e

When I populate a castle, dungeon, landscape etc - I want it all to make sense. For some monsters (like the Orc) the Monster Manual says what other monsters you would expect to find nearby - but is there a resource with this kind of information for other creatures?

For instance, I have a small dungeon with some Dark Elves... but having 3 or 4 rooms with yet more elves would get boring.   I could add a pen with some wolves... but that's an easy example.  Is there a nice tool which says "oh, you have Goblins.. they will play well with..... {whatever}.

I could just throw in a load of creatures, but common sense says that a dungeon full of different beasts would soon end up fighting before the PCs got there, and all the characters would find is a pile of monster corpses.

Is there any existing resource which will tell me what creatures are often found together in dungeons?

Comment: I don't think this can be meaningfully answered - depending on your world, goblins might be slaves of drow, or they might be the drow's most bitter enemy. Even within a world, it's pretty easy to come up with an explanation for almost *any* combination of monsters.

Comment: It could also depend on whether you're working with a published world or not and which version of DnD you are using

Comment: D&D 5th Edition.   I know it was a difficult question to answer... its just that there are quite a few encounter builders out there.. but none filter by creature compatability

Comment: how are you defining 'compatibility'?

Comment: When I say Compatibility, I mean put them in two rooms connected by a corridor, and they wont automatically kill each other above anything else (without having to put locked doors in the way)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are effectively looking for some sort of "friend/neutral/hostile" list that lists every combination of monster A vs monster B?

Comment: I don't think this question should be on hold. I understand it well enough. Globlinoids would all hang together, similarly with dragonoids. The current Tyranny of Dragons demonstrates that dragonoids work together sometimes. In the underdark I can think of a few, though don't have the MM on me nor have it memorized even a little, but the elves themselves obviously, dueger, some sort of cave gnomes (if they still are around in 5e), Spiders of course, various underground "creatures". Maybe a beholder or two past the edges of elven territory. The underdark is just like the overworld in that way.

Comment: A fantastic scenario might actually be to have your party encounter two opposing factions, that are both also hostile to the PCs. Like drow and goblins.

Comment: @Escoce Globlinoids of different types don't necessarily get along; Globlinoids tend to be jerks, after all, and many an adventure describes one group as enslaving or bullying some other group. The Svirfneblin were actually noted for being bitter enemies of the Drow and dark dwarves in the Forgotten Realms setting, so finding them allied with one of those other races might make much less sense than you'd think... There are very few hard-and-fast setting conventions, here.